# Letting Copper sit in NaOH for 5 min (for monolayer assembly)

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, nanotechnology

i made a self-assembled monolayer of dodecanethiol on copper, before that i let the copper in a solution of $\ce{NaOH}$ for 5 min, and i need to know what this step is for, anyone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! For formatting help visit the [help] center and for more information about this page, take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Such steps are usually cleaning steps to remove deposited organic materials. $\ce{NaOH}$ is also known as lye and will dissolve basically all organics. In this case, it should leave the $\ce{Cu}$ and copper oxides alone, leaving a clean surface.

I don't have as much experience with copper monolayers, but similar cleaning steps are used in my lab, where you might treat with ozone or some other step to remove any deposited organic "gunk" from the metal surface.

In this case, I believe you *don't* want to use an acid, because the thiols react with the copper oxide surface, not strictly the copper itself.